# Spring authorization logic in WebApi

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm building an Web Api with Spring, basically is to get Students, Teacher and Class, among other stuff.

Only the teacher of the class is supposed to be able to add Students.

So far, I'm authenticating the users with their username and password, but now I also have to check if it's the Teacher of the class that's trying to add a Student. Should I do this on the Controller or on the Service? Also I have to access the DB to make this check.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) interface has a set of authorities.  These are your roles, you could add specific class access here.  Then you can secure the controller method as appropriate.

You can create your own [GrantedAuthority](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/authority/SimpleGrantedAuthority.html) class to implement this.

Your [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) will add these roles to the user when they authenticate.

To get the current authenticated user and the classes they are allowed to work on, in the controller:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = auth.getAuthorities();
```

However if you want to do it with the entities, The class has many students and one teacher so that would suggest the class entity has a oneToOne to the teacher entity and a oneToMany to the student entity.  Then everything is controlled by class.  You would probably have a class service which has an addStudent() method, the check for teacher could then be done here.

Comment: I already saw that, the question is the role is dependent of the class. Because if it's a teacher of another class can't add a Student

Answer (score 0):

I would create a one-to-many/one-to-one relationship on the teacher model and then have a service method that checks if the teacher in question is in said list. I would use the service since they are supposed to provide business-methods. And then probably just call that method from the controller on the put/post call.

Comment: And should I get the current logged user on Controller and passe it to the Service, or get the current logged user directly in the service?

Comment: I'd say it's good to let the controller handle more than the request itself.

Comment: I mean not. Anyway make it so, that you dont have to do it at more then one places. So in case you need to change something you dont have to change code in multiple places.

Comment: What about have a Service method that check if the user is authorized to do the operation, then call the 2nd service method to do the job. If it's not authorized return 403 error

Comment: To check if the user is a teacher you should use the method essex boy gave you in the other answer. To check if the teacher is actually the teacher of the class he is trying to edit use a service method. If you are implementing authentication yourself, have seperate methods to check these things.